# curl_exec printing results when I don't want to

Tags: php, curl

I am using the following code:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 12); 

$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close ($ch);
```

However it's printing the results straight away. Is it possible to put the JSON result into a variable so I can print it out when I want to?

Comment: in the code you post i dont see any print

Comment: That's the point, That segment of code is printing the curl results when im not asking it too.

Answer (score 203, accepted):

Set `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` option:

```
// ...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Per [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php):

> `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` - **`TRUE`** to return the transfer as a string of the return value of `curl_exec()` instead of outputting it out directly.

Comment: Your linked doc says "From PHP 5.1.3, this option has no effect: the raw output will always be returned when CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER is used". I am not quite sure that I understand that, being a Mawg of very little brain, and I still have the same problem as O.P

Comment: Looks like this note in PHP documentation is related to CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER option, not CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER option.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried?

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
```

This worked for me!

Answer (score -8):

after php 5.1 `curl` will display always result you can view in documentation. for avoid it simply use

```
echo "< span style='display:none'>";

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 12);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close ($ch);

echo"< /span>";
```

Comment: `curl`'s behaviour is configurable, but if you really come across something that can't be configured to return the value instead of printing it, you should really use `ob_start()` before you call it, and `ob_get_clean()` after. The return value of `ob_get_clean()` will be the content that otherwise would've been printed. Take a look at the documentation of these functions to learn about them. Your answer is really not decent, so I thought you might learn from these. Didn't mean to offend you. Good luck!

Comment: Actually the problem with this answer (besides the points the previous commenter mentioned) is that it doesn't answer the question. It hasn't been mentioned if it is a web application or not, so you cannot be sure how output is displayed (it could even be a console application).